# mysql results by date future and past

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get records from database for last 14 days, and future 14 days only. The past I can get, but future is a problem.

Here is a sample of what dating format I'm trying (8 day sample) which works fine on my server:

```
mysql> select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +8 DAY);
+-------------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +8 DAY) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2017-09-07                          |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY);
+-------------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2017-09-23                          |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This seems to work fine to get past and future dates but, when trying it inline with my actual query it doesn't want to work for future dating.

```
mysql> SELECT estatu,edates,etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE edates 
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +8 DAY) AND CURDATE();
+----------+------------+--------+
| estatu   | edates     | etimes |
+----------+------------+--------+
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 19:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 17:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 15:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 |        |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 |        |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 | 19:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 | 19:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 | 19:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 09:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 12:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 15:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 17:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 18:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 19:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 20:30  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 |        |
+----------+------------+--------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT estatu,edates,etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE edates 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY) AND CURDATE();

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the nearest I got so far trying various script found here and elsewhere on the net.

This Query is just to confirm I have future events:

```
mysql> SELECT estatu,edates,etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE edates 
LIMIT 10;                                                                                                   
+----------+------------+--------+
| estatu   | edates     | etimes |
+----------+------------+--------+
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 19:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 17:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 17:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-23 | 15:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-23 | 17:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 15:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 |        |
| Results  | 2017-03-26 |        |
| Results  | 2017-04-02 |        |
| Results  | 2017-04-09 |        |
+----------+------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT: I need two separate results, one for future events, one for past events. Each will be requested independently from separate PHP page connections.

=========

## SOLUTION:

Thanks to @etsa the problem found to be the format. The below two queries provide exactly what is required, again with an 8 day sample:

```
SELECT estatu,edates,etimes FROM tevent WHERE edates BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +8 DAY) AND CURDATE();
SELECT estatu,edates,etimes FROM tevent WHERE edates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY);
```

The results looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT estatu,edates,etimes FROM tevent WHERE edates BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +8 DAY) AND CURDATE();
+----------+------------+--------+
| estatu   | edates     | etimes |
+----------+------------+--------+
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 19:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 17:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 15:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 |        |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 |        |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 | 19:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 | 19:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-08 | 19:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 09:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 12:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 15:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 17:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 18:00  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 19:30  |
| Results  | 2017-09-09 | 20:30  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 |        |
+----------+------------+--------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT estatu,edates,etimes FROM tevent WHERE edates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY);
+----------+------------+--------+
| estatu   | edates     | etimes |
+----------+------------+--------+
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 19:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 | 17:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 17:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-23 | 15:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-23 | 17:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 |        |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-15 |        |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 19:30  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 09:30  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 19:30  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 14:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 15:00  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-16 | 19:30  |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-17 |        |
| Upcoming | 2017-09-17 |        |
+----------+------------+--------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT estatu,edates,etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE edates 
BETWEEN  CURDATE() AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't getting future dates because your between isn't right:

```
SELECT estatu,edates,etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE edates 
    BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +8 DAY);
```

In the between clause, lower (earlier) value first, higher value second.

Comment: Many thanks @sloan-thrasher, but I find when only using "WHERE edates 
   DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +8 DAY);" seprate it still don't provide results

Comment: If that is the exact clause you used, it shouldn't produce any results. use ```edates <= DATE_ADD```... instead

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers give you exactly what you asked for, but this does:

```
SELECT
    estatu,
    edates,
    etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE
    edates BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND
                   DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

If you wanted separate queries for past and present you could use:

```
SELECT estatu, edates, etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE edates BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

for past and this for future:

```
SELECT estatu, edates, etimes 
FROM tevent 
WHERE edates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Comment: Many thanks @tim-biegeleisen, your answer works for a combined result, but as two separate queries it did't provide the required results. I should have been more clear on my request.

Comment: You probably broke up the query incorrectly.  Let me update.